# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

error when i start android studio Emulator in ubuntu

```
 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_3a_API_29], use -list-avds to see valid list.

 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```